# How can I disable a button that is belongs to a view who is added to another as local in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I have a big *.xaml file (let's call it FromView.xaml) that creates a view composed of multiple stack panels with buttons and labels etc.. This view is displayed as a tab in the main window, among others.
I also have a summary view (lets call it ToView.xaml) as a tab, that displays certain parts from each tab. 
Here is the problem, I want to add this FromView to ToView, but I don't want to show the buttons in it. I already managed to combine display FromView in ToView:

```
<!-- ToView.xaml -->
<Canvas MinHeight="300" MinWidth="750" Margin="2">
    <local:FromView Height="300" Width="750" IsSimplifiedView="True"/>
</Canvas>
```

In addition, I just need to access the visibility property of the buttons in the FromView from ToView. Here is a snippet from the FromView, so that you can see the button in it:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Width="280" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource QualificationBackground}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--some stuff-->

        <Label Content="SomeContent"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="60" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Save"/>

        <!--some stuff-->
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Why are you using Canvas and not a Grid? That's first question, second question is CanExecute in your command will determine if you can use the button. Style it so when it is not enabled then it is Hidden. very very simple

Comment: Most of the code is legacy. I am not sure why they preferred Canvas in the first place. Everything seems to be hanging by a thread in this code so I am trying not change anything unless it is really necessary. I don't understand yout answer. I don't want to disable it in its own view, I want it to be hidden in the other view it is also displayed.

Answer (score 1):

> In addition, I just need to access the visibility property of the buttons in the FromView from ToView.

I am afraid you *cannot* do something like this in XAML.

```
<local:FromView someButton.Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

If you want to be able to set a property of a `Button` that is located in `FromView` from `ToView`, you will have to define dependency or wrapper properties in the `FromView` class.

For example:

```
public class FromView : UserControl
{
    public Visibility SomeButtonVisibility
    {
       get => someButton.Visibility;
       set => someButton.Visibility = value;
  }
}
```

**FromView.xaml:**

```
<Button x:Name="someButton" Content="Save"/>
```

**ToView.xaml:**

```
<local:FromView SomeButtonVisibility="Collapsed" />
```

If you want to be able to bind to `SomeButtonVisibility`, it has to be defined as a dependency property.

Instead of creating a wrapper or dependency property for each button, you could define one property called something like "ShowButtons" that sets the `Visibility` property of several (or all) buttons in `FromView`, e.g.:

```
private bool _showButtons;
public bool ShowButtons
{
    get => _showButtons
            set
    {
        _showButtons = value;
        if (_showButtons)
        {
            button1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            button2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ...
                }
        else
        {
            button1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            button2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Dependency Property to the FromView UserControl. For example it can be IsButtonsVisible .
Now we can use it as following:

```
<Canvas MinHeight="300" MinWidth="750" Margin="2">
    <local:FromView Height="300" Width="750" IsSimplifiedView="True"
      IsButtonsVisible="Hidden"/>
</Canvas>
```

FromView Code Behind with the Dependency Property :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsButtonsVisibleProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsButtonsVisible", typeof(Visibility),
         typeof(FromView)
    );

        public Visibility IsButtonsVisible
        {
            get => (Visibility)GetValue(IsButtonsVisibleProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsButtonsVisibleProperty, value);
        }
```

Button in the FromView will look as following:

```
<Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="60" 
   Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Save" Visibility={Binding 
   ElementName=Parent,Path=IsButtonsVisible}/>
```

The "Parent" is defined as the Name of the FromView UserControl.